# Firestore Cloud Function Times Out When called

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have a custom endpoint setup for my FireStore database.
For now, all I want is to print all values to console, but when I call it from a client, the request times out and the console only says:

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: The Firebase database
>   'project-name' has been disabled by a database owner.
>   (https://project-name-de56eb8.firebaseio.com)

Here's my code. Can anyone tell me what is (what thins are) wrong with it?

```
const util = require('util');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const language = require('@google-cloud/language');
const client = new language.LanguageServiceClient();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.post('/calculateAverage', async (request, response) => {

  const bodyUserId = request.body.id
  let query = admin.database().ref(`/user_info/`);

  try {
    const snapshot = await query.once('value');
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      console.log("key: " + childSnapshot.key + " value: " + childSnapshot.val())
    });

    response.send({"snapshot await": "ok"});
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('Error getting messages', error.message);
    response.send({"snapshot await error": error.message});
  }
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: You should contact Firebase support to figure out why that error message is shown.  https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: I believe because I'm very inexperienced at this I made a mistake somewhere that others can catch.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you no use firebase realtime data.
in the options of firebase you have database and next *Cloud Firestore and 
*Realtime Database, select Realtime Database and after, active this option and with this the solution